# Tracking down leaks in Ruby daemon

Tags: ruby, memory-leaks

We have a Ruby daemon running on Ruby 2.2.0 & Ubuntu 12.04 that recently started leaking a lot of memory. It grows to about 10GB of usage over 12 hours and then the growth seems to slow down.

We're not quite sure if it's due to a change we made or just that we're giving it more work to process.

We've tried the technique described in [this](http://blog.skylight.io/hunting-for-leaks-in-ruby/) blog post to track down the cause, but the results show that it only found a few megabytes of new objects (and only 150mb of total objects) created when the process had actually grown by a gigabyte.

We've also tried doing a core dump of the process and looking through that, but there don't seem to be any obvious clues there either (Mostly blank space with occasional random-looking binary data).

What are some strategies we can use to track down the issue?

Comment: What kind of processing is the daemon doing?